# Textarea deletes data-src from html content jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div container with an image in it. It has a `"data-src"`

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("div").html("<textarea>" + $("div").html() + "</textarea>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img dat-src="image.jpg" data-src="px.gif" />
</div>

<button>Click to edit</button>
```

Once I click on the button, the div is replaced by a textarea with the image without the `data-src`

How do I fix this issue?

I want the image appears "as is" in the new textarea

RESULT

```
   <div>
        <img src="image.jpg" />
   </div>
```

Comment: I think its working correctly in your snippet itself. What was the issue ? i can see the src attribute for the image after i clicked the button. Also am not sure what is the use additional `dat-src` attribute

Comment: Use [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) instead.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("div").children().wrap("<textarea>");
  $("pre").text($('section').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
<div>
  <img dat-src="image.jpg" data-src="px.gif" />
</div>
</section>

<pre></pre>

<button>Click to edit</button>
```

Changes to:

```
<div>
   <textarea><img dat-src="image.jpg" data-src="px.gif"></textarea>
</div>
```

It's doing exactly as you asked, however it's not valid really because the browser does not re-parse it.  However if you're trying to set the *content* of the text area, this is not the correct way.  The correct way would be:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var $div = $("div");
  var text = $div.html();
  var $textarea = $('<textarea></textarea>');
  $textarea.appendTo($div).val(text);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
<div>
  <img dat-src="image.jpg" data-src="px.gif" />
</div>
</section>


<button>Click to edit</button>
```